# Is $(B_{\tau_b + (t - \tau_b)} - B_{\tau_b})_{t \ge 0}$ independent of $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_b}$ for a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

It is known from the Strong Markov property of Brownian motion that, given a Brownian motion $B$ and the a.s. finite stopping time $\tau_b := \inf \{ t \ge 0: B_t = b \}$,
$$
(B_{\tau_b + t} - B_{\tau_b})_{t \ge 0}
$$
is independent of the stopped sigma algebra
$$
\mathcal{F}_{\tau_b} := \left \{A \in \sigma \left (\cup \mathcal F_t \right )\mid \forall t: \{ \tau_b \le t \} \cap A \in \mathcal F_t \right \}.
$$

> Does it also hold that
> $$
> (B_{\tau_b + (t - \tau_b)} - B_{\tau_b})_{t \ge 0} = (B_t - B_{\tau_b})_{t \ge 0}
> $$
> is independent of
> $$
> \mathcal{F}_{\tau_b} \quad ?
> $$

## Addendum


Looking at the second edition of the book this question came from (Brownian motion by R. Schilling and L. Partzsch), instead of the first edition, I found that the equation that confused me have been changed. Now the claim seems rather to be that the probabilities of the sets
$$
\left\{\tau_b \le t \right \} \bigcap \left\{ B_{\tau_b + (t - \tau_b)} - B_{\tau_b} < 0 \right\}
$$
and
$$
\left\{\tau_b \le t \right \} \bigcap \left\{ B_{\tau_b + (t - \tau_b)} - B_{\tau_b} > 0 \right\}.
$$
are equal. Though some reference still seems to be made to that
$$
\left\{ B_{\tau_b + (t - \tau_b)} - B_{\tau_b} < 0 \right\} \in \mathcal{F}_\infty^W := \sigma\left (\bigcup B_{\tau_b + t} - B_{\tau_b} \right )
$$
(but perhaps it isn't claimed that the whole process $B_{\tau_b + t} - B_{\tau_b}$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal F_\infty^W$ and thus independent of $\mathcal F_{\tau_b}$).

Here is an excerpt from (the second edition of) the book
[image]

> I would still like help to verify that
> $$
> \mathrm P \left\{\tau_b \le t \right \} \bigcap \left\{ B_{\tau_b + (t - \tau_b)} - B_{\tau_b} < 0 \right\} = \mathrm P \left\{\tau_b \le t \right \} \bigcap \left\{ B_{\tau_b + (t - \tau_b)} - B_{\tau_b} > 0 \right\}.
> $$

Comment: I have tried a few different calculations with no luck. Intuitively I feel like it should not be true, since the process $B_{t}-B_{\tau_b} = B_{t} - b$ can not be equal to $0$ prior to time $\tau_b > 0$, while it has to approach $0$ for $t\to \tau_b$. Isn't it like saying the past is independent from the future?

Comment: Good observation @user7924249 . I had a look at the second edition of the book my question originated from and have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your original formulation, I believe the result is false, since $B_{t}-B_{\tau_b} = B_{t} -b$ cannot be equal to $0$ prior to time $\tau_b$, while it must tend to $0$ as $t\to\tau_b$.

In the revised version of the book, the statement seems more clear. Note that we restrict ourselves to the event that $\tau_b \leq t$, so we then know that $B_{t}-B_{\tau_b}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_b}$ by the strong Markov property. I.e., we are now looking into the past, as opposed to the ambiguous case in the first version. Also, by the strong Markov property we have that $(B_{t}-B_{\tau_b})_{t\geq \tau_b}$ is a Brownian motion, implying that $B_{t}-B_{\tau_b}\sim N(0,t - \tau_b)$. So then by symmetry of the normal distribution we have
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\lbrace \tau_b\leq t\rbrace\cap\lbrace B_{t}-B_{\tau_b} < 0 \rbrace\right)= \mathbb{P}\left( \lbrace \tau_b \leq t\rbrace\cap\lbrace B_{t}-B_{\tau_b} > 0\rbrace \right)
$$
Now just substitute $B_{t}=B_{\tau_b + (t-\tau_b)}$ and I believe we are done. The crucial step seems to be that restrict ourselves to $\lbrace \tau_b \leq t\rbrace$.

**Edit**: Regarding the symmetry of the normal distribution, it is of course not true in general, that $\mathbb{P}(A\cap \lbrace B_{t} <0 \rbrace) = \mathbb{P}(A\cap \lbrace B_{t} > 0\rbrace)$ for any $A$.
The following argument is used in Le Gall's book on Brownian motion and stochastic calculus:

We have $(\tau_b , B_{\tau_b + t - \tau_b} - B_{\tau_b}) \overset{d}{=}(\tau_b, B_{\tau_b} - B_{\tau_b + t - \tau_b})$ where this distribution is the product of the law of $\tau_b$ with the Wiener measure on $C(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})$. (technically I guess we need an indicator function to ensure finiteness of the stopping time). Then set
$$
H = \lbrace (s,w)\in \mathbb{R}_{+}\times C(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})\mid s\leq t, w(t-s) \leq 0 \rbrace
$$
where $w\mapsto w(t)$ is the coordinate map on the space of continuous functions on the positive half-line. Then we have
$$
\mathbb{P}((\tau_b,B_{\tau_b + t - \tau_b}-B_{\tau_b})\in H) = \mathbb{P}((\tau_b,-(B_{\tau_b + t - \tau_b}-B_{\tau_b}))\in H)
$$
and also
$$
\mathbb{P}((\tau_b,B_{\tau_b + t - \tau_b}-B_{\tau_b})\in H) = \mathbb{P}(\tau_b \leq t, B_{\tau_b + t - \tau_b}- B_{\tau_b}\leq 0)
$$
from where the desired symmetry follows.

Comment: Thanks! What you write makes intuitive sense. But I would still like to very it a little bit more thoroughly. First, if one take the normal distribution to be defined through its density function, then one could prove that $X \sim N(0, t) \implies P(X >0)=P(X<0)$ through integrating the density. But as you have written $B_t - B_{\tau_b} \sim N(0, t- \tau_b)$ has a random parameter, so integrating would be more complicated (e.g. we would first need to figure out a density). Secondly, if $P(X>0)=P(X<0)$ it is not certain that $P(A \cap \{X <0\})=P(A \cap \{X <>0\})$, so why does this hold for

Comment: $A= \{\tau_b \le t \}$ and $X=B_t - B_{\tau_b}$?

Comment: I agree that it is not as rigorous as one could hope for. I believe the distribution would have to be considered pathwise, $\omega$ for $\omega$. As long as we are on $\lbrace \tau_b \leq t\rbrace$, we know that the variance is some finite number, so we know that the normal distribution is symmetric around 0. The density of $\tau_b$ is actually known to be $f(t)=\frac{b}{\sqrt{2\pi t^{3}}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{2t}}\mathbb{1}_{t > 0}$, which is the same as that of $\frac{b^2}{B_{t}^{2}}$. Perhaps one could make some more from this. Regarding your second point, I will try to clarify in an edit.

Comment: The problem with the known density for $\tau_b$ is that it is usually derived from what I'm trying to prove here, so using that would be circular!

Comment: Oh, I see. I did not remember that it was that way around. I suppose that since the Brownian motion has a symmetric distribution, so does the pair $(\tau_b , B)$  and $(\tau_b , -B)$, where this distribution is the product of the distribution of $\tau_b$ and the Wiener measure on $C(\mathbb{R}_{+},\mathbb{R})$. Considering $\mathbb{P}((\tau_b , t)\in A) $ for an appropriate set $A$ might give the desired?

Comment: I re-edited and added an argument from Le Gall's book, which I believe shows the desired. This does however require developing the Wiener measure first.

Comment: I gave you the bounty for all your effort, but I am still not convinced by your argument. If we consider the distribution o f $(\tau_b, B_t  - B_{\tau_b})$ and $(\tau_b, -(B_t  - B_{\tau_b}))$ to be that of the product of the distributions of  $\tau_b$ and $B_t  - B_{\tau_b}$, and $\tau_b$ and $-(B_t - B_{\tau_v}$, respectively, then per construction we are considering $\tau_b$ and $B_t - B_{\tau_b}$ (and $\tau_b$ and $-(B_t - B_{\tau_v}$) to be independent. But in this case it is already trivial to get the desired equality just from symmetry of the normal distribution.

Comment: So in this case, the question would still be is $\tau_b$ and $B_t - B_{\tau_b}$ independent?